# Andengine vibrator issue

Tags: android, andengine

I am using Andengine in my game. The issue I face is that when my application goes in background, the screen blanks out on resume. This is happens when I include

```
@Override
public void onGameCreated() {
    this.mEngine.enableVibrator(this);
}
```

in the BaseGameActivity extending class. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, or so I think. Instead of initializing the vibrator in onGameCreated(), i did it in on Resume(), and it works.

```
    @Override
protected synchronized void onResume() {
    this.mEngine.enableVibrator(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```